# How do I check the current progress of URLSession.dataTaskPublisher?

Tags: swift, combine

I'm using a `dataTaskPublisher` to fetch some data:

```
func downloadData(_ req: URLRequest) {
  self.cancelToken = dataTaskPublisher(for: req).sink { /* ... */ }
}
```

If the function is called while the request is in progress, I would like to return.

Currently I either:
1. Set the `cancelToken` to nil in the sink or
2. Crate and manage a `isDownloading` variable.

Is there a built-in way to check if the `dataTaskPublisher` is running (and optionally its progress)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I mostly agree with @Rob, however you can control state of `DataTask` initiated by `DataTaskPublisher` and its progress by using of `URLSession` methods:

```
func downloadData(_ req: URLRequest) {
    URLSession.shared.getAllTasks { (tasks) in
        let task = tasks.first(where: { (task) -> Bool in
            return task.originalRequest?.url == req.url
        })

        switch task {
        case .some(let task) where task.state == .running:
            print("progress:", Double(task.countOfBytesReceived) / Double(task.countOfBytesExpectedToReceive))
            return
        default:
            self.cancelToken = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: req).sink { /* ... */ }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can someone maybe explain how this works and where you would call this in order to get regular updates to the progress?

Comment: @Björn You can find a task by url and then check task.countOfBytesReceived and task.countOfBytesExpectedToReceive for getting of the progress. For regular updates you should use a timer.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding getting progress from this publisher, looking at the [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/88b093e9d77d6201935a2c2fb13f27d961836777/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/Publishers%2BURLSession.swift#L23), we can see that it’s just doing a completion-block-based data task (i.e. `dataTask(with:completionHandler:)`). But the resulting `URLSessionTask` is a private property of the private `Subscription` used by `DataTaskPublisher`. Bottom line, this publisher doesn’t provide any mechanism to monitor progress of the underlying task.

As Denis pointed out, you are limited to querying the `URLSession` for information about its tasks.